# Android 9 - Trouble orchestrating multiple stacked VideoView objects SM-G950U

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, android-videoview

I've been struggling to get a common viewing area on the display to be shared by multiple video streams.
The streams are selected by touching on a thumbnail of the stream contained in a layout below the main viewing area containing a matrix of all the thumbnails.
The streams are being managed by GStreamer and from the screenshot, you can see the streams are flowing.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snkqZ.jpg)

The left thumbnail at the bottom of the screenshot is displayed in the main viewing area when the app starts.

The desired behavior is when the OnClickListener fires when touching the thumbnail on the right, the current VideoView object should go in the background and the new VideoView object in reference to the onClick event should come into the foreground, on top of the previous one.

I've tried combinations of sharing the main VideoView object and trying to swap the underlying Surface object, as well as removing the old VideoView object from the main viewer layout and adding the new selected VideoView object to the main layout.

Currently, I have a VideoView object for each thumbnail stream and a VideoView object for the main viewer stream (via a tee element in the GStreamer pipeline).  I'm trying combinations of 
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) as well as setZOrderMediaOverlay(true), setZOrderMediaOverlay(false) and setZOrderOnTop(true), setZOrderOnTop(false).

If I do setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), the surface in the VideoView object is destroyed, but the new selected object is displayed.  the setZOrder* methods alone don't seem to have a desired effect.

Is there a way to hide a VideoView & its surface without the surface getting destroyed while another VideoView is executing visually on top?  Is that the recommended way?

It's hard to tell from the posts I've been scouring to solve the problem.

Thanks for any feedback.
- Doug

Comment: A few questions. What exactly do you mean by "background"? Behind/hidden? If a given `VideoView` isn't on screen, why do you care if the `Surface` gets destroyed? (Moreover, why can't you tolerate losing a `Surface`? That's a normal part of the `VideoView` lifecycle). Is your intent to have 2 `VideoViews` going for a given stream, if it's currently selected, or is moving a `VideoView` from the layout to the main viewing area what you want?

Comment: Yes, background == Behind/hidden.  The streams are continuously running to the thumbnail and (hidden) main VideoView object, so if the hidden surface gets destroyed, it disrupts the GStreamer video stream pipeline.  I haven't figured out a way yet to get GStreamer to recover the stream to the main VideoView object when it goes back into focus (unhidden) after being selected again by a touch to the thumbnail VideoView.  The intent is to 2 VideoViews going for a given stream.

Comment: It is acceptable if the surface being destroyed after being hidden can be restarted by GStreamer when a new surface is created when it becomes unhidden again, without restarting the entire video stream, but picking up from the current video frame that is being displayed in the thumbnail VideoView object.  Hope that makes sense : S

Comment: It seems likely to me that your solution lies in GStreamer, not `VideoView` or related framework features. I have upvoted your question, to help gain attention from the right people.

Comment: Thanks for your help @greeble31.  I'll take a look down the GStreamer trail and see what shakes loose on SO or GStreamer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I went back to using a single layout for the main viewing area with a main viewing VideoView object for each stream.  Then I split the GStreamer pipeline feeding each main viewer stream into 2 pipelines as such with these launch string example snippets:

1st: (Other leg of the tee goes to the thumbnail stream)
tee ! appsink

2nd:
appsrc ! videoscale !  glimagesink

Now, when a main VideoView object is destined to go out of focus due to another being selected, I set the 2nd pipeline state to PAUSED for it and the main VideoView stream state to PLAYING for the selected stream.  This allows GStreamer to kind of handle the buffer draining itself while the underlying surfaces get shuffled by the framework.
I also remove the outgoing VideoView child view from the layout and add the selected incoming VideoView to the layout.

I have some pretty standard code for the appsink and appsrc from the GStreamer examples for those elements on managing transferring samples across the 2 pipelines.  I didn't even have to manage caps filters to get it to work, which is nice as I was expecting I might have to do something.